# is there any help for bootstrap and react-router in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new in `React`, and I use `react-router` and `bootstrap` version 3.4 examples section.

First example - when I run my project doesn't show my project. I will show the codes:

```
import React from "react"
class Header extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
              </div>
              <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        )
    }
}
export default Header
```

The `href` attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the `href` value. If you cannot provide a valid `href`, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles.

Answer (score 0):

this may help

Both  and  components can be used to define and design declarative navigation around an application. Within either component, we can use the “to” attribute to specify the location pathname to which the link will direct.

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

  <NavLink to="/" className="<any classes like>float-left">Home</NavLink>
  <NavLink to="/about" className="<any classes like>float-left">About</NavLink>
```

here is a great example 
https://medium.com/swlh/using-react-router-navlink-to-specify-the-active-element-in-a-navigation-bar-38700ffd4900